# Installing and Upgrading Intern without NPM

Tags: intern

Is there any way to install Intern without npm?

I'm not going to get the rights to download files through our corporate proxy and I can't convince anyone to spend a few dollars to upgrade to Artifactory Pro and use its npm support.

Comment: When you say you can't get rights to download files...you mean you can't even download it through [GitHub](https://github.com/theintern/intern)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could download it from GITHub [https://github.com/theintern/intern/releases/tag/2.2.2] at home, or on a computer of a friend (outside of the Proxy). But that are the sources which must be compiled. And even if you could download the node module then, there still be dependencies, which would have been resolved by hand. (npm could not add them automatically).

One idea is to put your project on a stick or external HD. Take it to Computer outside of the proxy. Install node on this computer. Install Intern and put it back to the work computer.